# When I try to export my app in live code it comes up with an error message

Tags: livecode

The error message is "There was an error while saving the standalone application device build requires a provisioning file to be chosen"
I know it probably trivial to some but I've only just started

Comment: Have you chosen a provisioning file?

Comment: I don't know how to :/

Comment: Then that should be your question.

Comment: Oh sorry do you know how do set one? and if you do could you please help me learn sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have set up your iOS developers account with Apple and have installed XCode, you should see your provision profiles appear in XCode's organizer window. If you can see those, you can open the iOS pane of the Standalone Application Settings in LiveCode and choose `iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *` from the Profile option menu button.

This is sufficient to test your app on your own device. Just drag the app from the place where it appears after building the standalone onto the icon of your iOS device in XCode.

Comment: And see Dave Kilroy's comment above about signing up with Apple.com.

Answer (score 0):

In standalone application settings, iOS, there is a drop down menu "Profile". That's where you choose the profile from. It will only be showing provisioning profiles that you have installed from your iPhone Developer account, so if you don't have such an account, or have not downloaded any profiles, the list will be empty.

Comment: Go here: https://developer.apple.com and sign up. Please note it isn't free, $99 per year if memory serves...